# Can i please know that how can we make a table such as this one in html , i mean the border style of this type

Tags: html-table

[This image shows a table having edges drawn with slashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jibqv.png)
Drawing borders with common styles like dotted , dashed wouldn't be a problem but i'm not quite
familiar with this type of border.

Answer (score 0):

The [border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) property would be one way to achive an effect like this. You would prepare an image (a PNG, SVG, or some other format) with just the borders, like so:

```
/--\
|  |
|  |
\--/
```

...and then set the `border-image` to that image. The slicing properties makes it so that the corners are "cut" out of the image; the straight line segments can be either stretched or repeated. Some examples on the linked page have all corners be the same shape, but this is not required.

Putting all that together, the result looks like this:

[image: small example]

```css
table {
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDIIB.png') 8 repeat;  
}
```

```html
<table><tr><td>table content</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: The answer is quite helpful but i still seem to only get borders on the entire table only on the outside , the rows and columns aren't getting divided by the dashed border

Comment: can you please tell that how can we add this border style for row and column division as well

Comment: The internal borders are just normal dashed borders, right? Those could be done with just `border-style: dashed;`, you shouldn't need border-image for those.

Comment: the issue i face with this approach is that after doing this , the table cells create a parallel border line side by side with the table border , i need to make it as if the inner border is only there as a separator between each row and column instead of completely covering each cell , like in the image i've attached